INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY when upserting a custom object record via API
I've written a new API in GoLang to handle object syncs from our proprietary software to sync with the records in Salesforce following the steps to "Upsert a Record" in Salesforce on the following article:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.244.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm
Currently, the UPDATE portion of "Upsert" works perfectly fine, but the INSERT portion does not work.
If the Record already exists, it UPDATEs the Record normally, however, if the Record does not exist in Salesforce, I get a 400 error:
code=400 err="[{invalid cross reference id INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY}]" status="400 Bad Request"

I am making the Upsert Request to a Custom Object type in Salesforce and the cURL call endpoint is as follows:
PATCH: https://SALESFORCEBASEURL/services/data/v60.0/sobjects/myCustomObject__c/ExternalField__c/ExternalFieldId"

I haven't experimented yet with trying to call an NON-custom Object in Salesforce (like Account or Opportunity), and currently that is my only assumption as to why this is not correctly INSERTing when the Record does not exist. Any insights?

INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY is usually a permission issue on a related record.  Your question doesn't show it but hopefully you're sending a JSON payload as the body of your request with all of the fields required by your custom object.  You'll want to get in touch with the admin of this org and go over the data model and permissions.

yes, I'm sending a JSON payload over with the request as well. Could the issue be limited to a single field's permissions in that payload? Or would it explicitly be the permission to "INSERT" a new record?

Could be any of the above, unfortunately. Your best bet is to check with the org admin.
